# How can iterate over all the settings in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

How can I iterate over all the Django settings? I need to read all the settings which begin with `MYAPP_`.

I've tried doing this:

```
from django.conf import settings

for setting in settings:
    print setting
```

...but i get the following exception:

```
TypeError: 'LazySettings' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for s in dir(settings):
    print s, ':', getattr(settings, s)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to call [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) on it.

```
from django.conf import settings
print dir(settings)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for name in filter(lambda x: x.startswith('MYAPP_'), dir(settings)):
    # ...
```